# Is it possible to make secure my vimeo course videos?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have vimeo pro plan, i want to encrypt my vimeo videos, users are downloading my course videos.

Is there any way i can stop downloading, First i was using iframe videos were downloading, I embed vimeo player videos are downloading. When i tried base64 encryption videos are not playing.

```
<?php
                     
    $filecontent1 = file_get_contents('524933864');
    $data = base64_encode($filecontent);


echo"<div id='myVideo' data-vimeo-id='data:text/html;base64,$data' data-vimeo-width='600'></div>";

?>
<script>
  var videoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('myVideo');
  videoPlayer.on('play', function() {
    console.log('Played the video');
  });


</script>


Is there any way i can stop downloading?
```

Comment: Given that the browser will need to download the video to display it, there is no technically secure way to prevent a download. This is also not something you could solve with either php nor javascript I suppose.

Comment: Is it possible with other language?

Comment: Like with node.js or python etc?

Comment: Why would they be any different, do you imagine? The same process has to occur - the browser needs to be able to access the video in order to show it. This involves the browser downloading the video from the server to the computer where the browser is running. If there is a setting in vimeo itself (which the answer below suggests there might be) to control privacy then that would make more sense.

Comment: `base64 encryption`...base64 is an _encoding_ mechanism. It's not encryption. Anything encoded with base64 can be directly decoded just from the data, without needing any kind of encryption key or other security mechanism. So even if you'd made it work, it wouldn't have provided any security. When making any kind of technology choice like this, please make sure you know what the technology you're using actually _is_, and what you can do with it.

Comment: Is there anyway i can make my videos secure? Users are not able to download video? I know on internet it's really difficult to make every thing secure. But i want to make it difficult to download. Thanks

Comment: It has to be downloaded in order to go to the browser and be shown. Are you saying that people then have a way to copy it to their machine permanently? How can you tell that is happening, exactly?

Comment: I know video hast to be downloaded to show in browser,I am talking about offline downloading, people download videos and save videos on their devices and share them! Simply means they are using downloaders like IDM to download my videos!

Comment: How have you proved that is happening?

Comment: I can download from my end! ( Video Downloader PLUS ) from this google chrome extension, proving that my videos are not secure! I turned off downloading option from vimeo dashboard! But videos are downloading!

Comment: Maybe you should raise this with vimeo support then, if they claim they have a setting to prevent it. If the video is hosted on their site then any security needs to be implemented there, you can't affect it from anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the single video management page, you should see a lock icon on the right for privacy settings. In there you should be able to configure who can download the video and which domain the users are able to access the video from. [Settings Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Swd.png). If this still doesn't work, feel free to reach out to me at hedy.tang@vimeo.com and I can take a look.

Comment: I'm using privacy setting of vimeo, but still i am facing that user are downloading videos!! I already turned off video download and using domain level privacy. Still videos are downloading

Comment: Can I see where you are embedding the videos?

Comment: https://lms.femitech.org/dashboard/new.php

Comment: Please check this URL here i embedded vimeo player and added a lecture of my course!